HI im new to android studio im able to build my app successfully but it crashes in emulater
when i build my app the following task output :
Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
but its builds successfully but the app crashes in the emulater with the following reasons
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.asmaa.perfectpost, PID: 15042
java.lang.AssertionError
at com.asmaa.perfectpost.Frag.MyTemplatesNewFragment$3.onSuccess(SourceFile:154)
at com.asmaa.perfectpost.Serv.AppRestClient$1.returnSuccess(SourceFile:47)
at com.asmaa.perfectpost.Serv.AppRestClient$3$2.run(SourceFile:114)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)

Main error output: https://i.sstatic.net/HlUFL.png
Additional informations:
https://i.sstatic.net/NEjlc.png
https://i.sstatic.net/yLTvK.png
https://i.sstatic.net/QedMA.png
https://i.sstatic.net/VQhUp.png
im not seeing any errors in the java source files  i hope someone could help

unexpected url: nullcategory means that base is null and not the real url (like https://server.com/) in your AppRestClient.java - that needs to be fixed, the notes you get are just info for you, nothing that breaks the app

Please post the code inside the question as text, not as images or as external links (to github or pastebin). If the code is complex or long, consider posting a smaller portion of the code as a MRE. Also, post any debugging results you performed so far.
